# Failed to install jupyter using pip

Tags: python-3.x, pip, jupyter

I tried to install jupyter using pip: `pip install jupyter` (even with admin privilege)

But for some reason it could not install it successfully. Here is the error:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement
>   widgetsnbextension~=3.3.0 (from ipywidgets->jupyter) (from versions:
>   1.0.0b2, 1.0.0b3, 1.0.0b4, 1.0.0b5, 1.0.0, 1.1.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 1.2.3, 1.2.4, 1.2.5, 1.2.6, 2.0.0b1, 2.0.0b2, 2.0.0b3, 2.0.0b4, 2.0.0b5, 2.0.0b6, 2.0.0b7, 2.0.0b8, 2.0.0b9, 2.0.0b10, 2.0.0b11, 2.0.0b12, 2.0.0b13, 2.0.0b14, 2.0.0b15, 2.0.0b16, 2.0.0b17, 2.0.0b18, 2.0.0b19, 2.0.0rc1, 2.0.0rc2, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 3.0.0a0, 3.0.0a1, 3.0.0a2, 3.0.0a3, 3.0.0a4, 3.0.0a5, 3.0.0a6, 3.0.0a7, 3.0.0a8, 3.0.0a9, 3.0.0a10, 3.0.0a11, 3.0.0a12, 3.0.0a13, 3.0.0a14, 3.0.0a15, 3.0.0b0, 3.0.0b1, 3.0.0b2, 3.0.0b3, 3.0.0b4, 3.0.0b5, 3.0.0b6, 3.0.0b7, 3.0.0b8, 3.0.0b9, 3.0.0b10, 3.0.0b11, 3.0.0b12, 3.0.0b13, 3.0.0rc0, 3.0.0rc1, 3.0.0rc2, 3.0.0, 3.0.1, 3.0.2, 3.0.3, 3.0.4, 3.0.5, 3.0.6, 3.0.7, 3.0.8, 3.1.0rc0, 3.1.0rc1, 3.1.0rc2, 3.1.0, 3.1.1, 3.1.2, 3.1.3, 3.1.4, 3.2.0, 3.2.1, 3.3.0b0) No matching distribution found for widgetsnbextension~=3.3.0 (from ipywidgets->jupyter)

*Note:* I also did `pip install widgetsnbextension` and there was no error. Yet I still could not install jupyter.

How shall I proceed?

Comment: `pip install widgetsnbextension --upgrade`, then reinstall `jupyter`. The 3.3.0 version is now available.

Comment: @hoefling Thank you very much! It worked. You can post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2):

you must first step:

```
pip install widgetsnbextension --upgrade
```

second step:

```
pip3 install --upgrade pip
pip3 install jupyter
jupyter notebook
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the commands:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install --upgrade jupyter
```

To run the notebook:

```
python3 -m pip notebook
```

or

```
jupyter notebook
```

A short demo:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gIRYMfkpsy4

This demo illustrates the steps from scratch, if the above steps don't work

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BVS3U1OQzO4

Answer (score 0):

If you are objective is to use Jupyter notebook, install Anaconda, it comes as a package where you have anaconda navigator and anaconda prompt to manage IDE and packages respectively.

You can straight away type "Jupyter Notebook" in Anaconda Prompt to use it.

Let's say, I need to use Jupyter notebook in a virtual environment

```
conda create --name venv
```

Now I want Jupyter in this virtual environment,

Go to Anaconda Navigator, select the desired environment, Use the Jupyter Notebook or any other IDEs.